# Is it possible to use condensation to establish an absolute ordering

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, particle-physics

Consider two electrons sit next to each other and move towards each other slowly in the rest frame. Because of the energy conservation, the on shell condition made sure that those two electrons would not suddenly scatter into pairs of other particles.(jets)

However, the energy was not an invariant quantity like that of the momentum.

Switching to a fast moving frame perpendicular to the two electrons, so fast such that the two electrons could be seen moving at relativistic energy. In this frame, the probability of which two electron interact and scatter into other pairs of particles seemed to be not zero, because the on shell condition could be satisfied. (And, aside, for the dilation of how "close" they were, as long as the probability was not zero than it should work.)

This seemed to have brought a contradiction.

In two reference frame, one stratified the on shell condition to produce more particles, the other one did not. Once the new particles were produced, the new particles were produced.

Thus, although the speed was relative and could not obtain an ordering, this "yes" or "no" on shell or off shell condition seemed to have enabled the possibility to establish an absolute ordering through the experimental observation. For example, consider a bunch of those particles sit in a cloud, the ones does not produce new particles were able to condense, while the ones produced more new particles suffered continuous statistical variations.

Is it possible to use condensation to establish an absolute ordering?

---

Thought it was understood then it was not.

Let's break from the Lorentz invariance and the invariant measure theory for a moment and see just what it would be seen in the experiment.

In a reference frame A when a pair of electron and position accelerate to $v_{e^+}=a c$ and $v_{e^-}=a c$ where $a=0.9999999$ and $c$ was the speed of the light, they could annihilate and generate heavy particles such as say a pair of the proton and antiproton.

Suppose the electron and position pair was close to each other but almost rest in the reference frame A.(No longer produce proton and antiproton pair) One set to the reference B which was a velocity of $-ac$ relative to the reference frame $A$. Then there's a pair of electron and position with $v_{e^+}=a c$ and $v_{e^-}=a c$, do they annihilate and produce proton and antiproton?

Notice that the reference A and the reference B should have the same observation. But the relativistic principle was to the law of the physics, not the law of the observation.

If it does not create the proton and antiproton pair, according to the invariant measure(The scattering amplitude did not change), then obviously the observation of the reference $A$ and the reference $B$ agree, but the physics does not (This contribute to the violation of relativistic principle since the law of the physics should agree in the difference reference frame, the same physics of a pair of electron position travel at $a c$ in difference frame does not produce the same result).

If it does create the proton and antiproton pair, then the observation from the reference A and the reference B does not agree, but the physics does agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A particle is on-shell if $E^2-p^2=m^2$. As the magnitude squared of the four-momentum, $E^2-p^2$ is Lorentz invariant. So if a particle is on-shell in one inertial reference frame, it's on-shell in all inertial reference frames.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $E^2-m^2$ was large enough to produce other on shell particles, exactly because $E$ was different in different reference frame while the 4 momentum $E^2-p^2=m^2$ .

Comment: @ShoutOutAndCalculate $E^2-m^2$ does not matter for producing particles. The energy available for producing particles is the center-of-momentum energy, $(\Sigma E)^2-(\Sigma\vec p)^2$, which is Lorentz invariant.

Comment: Right. (I forgot the condition was already implemented in the KG E.O.M. and the measure.)

Comment: Sorry. The scattering amplitude was Lorentz invariant in the QFT that part was clear but I got confused again by the relativistic principle. See updates.

Comment: @ShoutOutAndCalculate If two people walking next to each other bump shoulders, do you expect them to instead explode if you look at them while flying over in a plane? If two particles are at rest relative to one another in one reference frame, they cannot have the energy to produce particles heavier than themselves in *any* reference frame. By conservation of momentum, if the two particles have parallel velocities close to the speed of light, then the daughter particles must have the same (rather large!) momentum. There isn't enough energy to give a more massive particle that much momentum.

Comment: @ShoutOutAndCalculate I think perhaps the thing you are missing is that two particles with *opposite* velocities near the speed of light can produce heavier particles, but two particles with equal *parallel* velocities, regardless of magnitude, can not. These two situations are not related to one another by a Lorentz transformation.

Comment: Yes. The parallel(travel together) and the opposite velocity(a direct coalition) was in fact at the center of the argument. The question was how much. The probability was only zero if $\theta=0$, a measure zero in $[0,\pi)$. Thus, I was thinking about a $\delta v$, i.e. the "slowly moving towards each other" in the O.P., but in the scenario as with even a very small $\delta V$, the none zero angle $\theta\neq 0$ with a relativistic velocity $ac$ could be observed. That might be where the equation really confused the observation, i.e. how small or if possible to establish that $\delta v$.

Comment: The question was bothering first because the different types of the particles was a bit "topological", the original electron wave equation vanished after the annihilation and the yes or no question had the practical experimental effect. The other one was weather it was possible for the introduction of the "small" velocity $\delta V$, to introduce the none zero scattering angle $\theta\neq 0$, that brought the question weather the quantum gravity was required to resolve the scale(the smallness).

Comment: @ShoutOutAndCalculate The probability for two on-shell leptons to scatter into a proton and an antiproton is zero so long as $(\Sigma E)^2-(\Sigma\vec p)^2$ is less than $2m_p$. That's it. Again, that's Lorentz invariant, so it doesn't matter what frame you are in. "Physics" and "observation" are in complete agreement on this fact.

Comment: Light(rest mass) particles at high energy collide to generate heavy particles. The scattering process described in the post could be found in this paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0550321314002971 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron%E2%80%93positron_annihilation

Comment: @ShoutOutAndCalculate Light particles at high energy collide to generate heavy particles *only when their center of momentum energy is high*. Many colliders are *specifically* designed to maximize $(\Sigma E)^2-(\Sigma\vec p)^2$ for a given amount of input energy.

Comment: Yes. But the amplitude was not a Dirac function, it ought to be something like $\cos \theta$ was it?(Not quite sure, the argument hold when the probability was not zero, not when the probability was small.) But one thing though, if the annihilation process was too complicated, then consider the single particle scattering with the vacuum, or the jets generated by a single particle. Could they lead to the contradiction?

Comment: @ShoutOutAndCalculate Your "contradiction" is based in a misunderstanding of special relativity, not physics. You think that "big energy" means "can make particles." But that isn't true in general. All scattering probabilities are manifestly Lorentz invariant- it doesn't matter what frame you analyze them in, you get the same answer.

Comment: Oh! I made sense of your previous comment and that I should not have compared the electron photon scattering($\cos \theta$) with electron position annihilation scattering where a theta(step) function in the 4 momentum change should technically appear? But this still did not resolve the single particle scattering(jet), since the four momentum in this case the only relative velocity was with respect to the particle. Does that mean the single particle scattering necessarily involve the Lorentz transformation of the vacuum? But how experimentally could the vacuum to be seen Lorentz transferred?

Comment: @ShoutOutAndCalculate Single particles can't scatter *at all* because of the same conservation of energy and momentum. Particles can decay but again whether a particle decays or not is completely independent of what frame you analyze it from.

Comment: But I thought that say an electron being accelerated to such a high energy of a track then the electron should be able to interact with the vacuum and emite the massive particle pairs other than photons? i.e. use kinetic energy to generate mass. See this post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/186052/can-we-create-heavier-particles-with-high-energy the photon was relativistic enough and could generate electron positron pairs, but it red shifts.

Comment: @ShoutOutAndCalculate You thought wrong. If you want to understand this, start with the understanding that all scattering is the same regardless of what frame you analyze it in. A lone electron in its rest frame obviously can not scatter off anything. The same thing is true of a lone electron outside of its rest frame. The simple reason is that there is no way for the electron to scatter that preserves both energy and momentum. (As the answer by ACuriousMind on the very post you just linked to describes for a photon).

Comment: I got the feeling that a "relative collision" was needed to distinguish the rest frame, but still tried to find the (obviously wrong) examples from an experimental point of the view. This helped me to build the intuition from the other route. Thank you. The cases remain was the fluctuation from the uncertainty principle and the vacuum excitation, which either beyond the scope of the post or could be distinguished by the conservation.